# RegEx expression to select only the "o" 's between curly braces

Tags: regex, adobe-indesign

I am looking for a RegEx expression that selects only the o's that occur between the curly braces. This is not code. This is a data feed into InDesign.

I have figured out how to select everything between curly braces using:

```
(?<=\{).*?(?=\})
```

But I need to select ONLY the o's.

> {oR} {oR} o6oRoR
>   {oXoBoB} o6oRoR {o3} o6oRoR
>   {o2} o6oRoR {o2} o6oRoR
>   {oT} o6oRoR
>   {oT} o6oRoR
>   {o1oR}, {oT} o6oRoR
>   {o6oRoR} o6oRoR

Comment: Looks like you can only rely on a work around, `o(?=[^{}]*})`

Comment: That's it! I can use this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

As the variable-width lookbehind is not supported, you can't check exactly if `o` is in between `{` and `}`.

You may use a work around to match any `o` that is followed with any 0+ chars other than `{` and `}` and then a `}`:

```
o(?=[^{}]*})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ahwk1L/1).

**Details**

- `o` -  `o` char
- `(?=[^{}]*})` - a positive lookahead that requires, immediately to the right of the current location, 0+ chars other than `{` and `}` and then `}`.